# Yocto Project Bitbake Unexpected Termination

Tags: python, yocto, bitbake, nxp-microcontroller

I just got my [i.MX 8M Evaluation Kit](https://www.nxp.com/support/developer-resources/run-time-software/i.mx-developer-resources/evaluation-kit-for-the-i.mx-8m-applications-processor:MCIMX8M-EVK) and I followed the [tutorial](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/user-guide/i.MX_Yocto_Project_User's_Guide_Linux.pdf) to make the system for my board.

I build the system on a host machine with Ubuntu 16.04 and I followed all instructions in Section-3 to set up my host machine.

I'm trying to build the Wayland image with OPTEE enabled so the commands are:

```
$ DISTRO=fsl-imx-wayland MACHINE=imx8mqevk source fsl-setup-release.sh -b build-wayland

Comment two SDL settings in local.conf: PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl", PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"

Enable OPTEE in local.conf

$ bitbake fsl-image-qt5-validation-imx
```

The issue happens after the ***"bitbake"*** command, which is the script would suddenly be stopped and the host machine would be suspended and required re-login. The bitbake command can be continued with ***"-k" parameter*** while the unknown termination and re-login process are really annoying to me.

By reviewing the bitbake log file ***bitbake-cookerdeamon.log***, I found that every time before unexpected termination, the bitbake command generates the same logs:

```
Accepting [<socket.socket fd=7, family=AddressFamily.AF_UNIX,
type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=bitbake.sock>] Connecting
Running command ['updateConfig', ...]
Running command ['getVariable', 'BBINCLUDELOGS']
Running command ['getVariable', 'BBINCLUDELOGS_LINES']
Running command ['getSetVariable', 'BB_CONSOLELOG']
Running command ['getUIHandlerNum']
Running command ['setEventMask', ...]
Running command ['getVariable', 'BB_DEFAULT_TASK']
Running command ['setConfig', 'cmd', 'build']
Running command ['buildTargets', ['fsl-image-qt5-validation-imx'], 'build']
Running command ['stateForceShutdown']
Connecting Client
Disconnecting Client
No timeout, exiting.
Exiting
```

According to my current understanding, the above commands are only supposed to be executed after all tasks have been prepared. However, right now my host machine may invoke these commands during other tasks are still running, and this incorrect sequence leads to my unexpected termination issue.

I'm wondering if anyone runs to a similar problem or knows the solution to my issue?

Any suggestion is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Simon

-----Supplemental Information
Here is the content of the configuration file `fsl-imx-wayland.conf`

> # i.MX DISTRO for Wayland without X11
>
> include conf/distro/include/fsl-imx-base.inc include
>   conf/distro/include/fsl-imx-preferred-env.inc
>
> DISTRO = "fsl-imx-wayland"
>
> # Remove conflicting backends DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "directfb x11 " DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " wayland pam systemd"

Comment: what distro are you running on build host ?

Comment: @Khem I use "DISTRO=fsl-imx-wayland". Is this you asked for?

Comment: No I mean distro on build host

Comment: @Khem Could you please indicate how to get the distro information you want? According to my understanding, "distro layer" in the Yocto project just provides the configuration information for bitbake and I add the detailed distro file in my question.

Comment: Are you running bitbake on Ubuntu, Redhat, etc? That's the distro @Khem means

Comment: @kdopen thanks. As I defined at the beginning of my question, "I build the system on a host machine with Ubuntu 16.04".